# Python can't handle Windows long paths with parent directory parts

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to use `..` in a Windows long filename within Python and it is producing unexpected results.

Here is the output from the Python REPL:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists(u'\\\\?\\C:\\BitBucket\\crab6\\product\\installer\\windows\\..\\usage.txt')
False
>>> os.path.exists(u'\\\\?\\C:\\BitBucket\\crab6\\product\\installer\\usage.txt')
True
```

(I realize the path above isn't over 260 characters and therefore the long path syntax is unnecessary, but for the purposes of this post I've made it more manageable. The outcome is the same with very long paths.)

Has anyone else encountered this, and is it a purposeful limitation of long filenames?

Comment: Try `pathlib` instead. However, why/how should it be able to interpret `..`?

Comment: Good thought. Similar outcome though: `pathlib.Path(u'\\\\?\\C:\\BitBucket\\crab6\\product\\installer\\usage.txt').exists()` returns True, while `pathlib.Path(u'\\\\?\\C:\\BitBucket\\crab6\\product\\installer\\windows\\..\\usage.txt').exists()` raises `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '\\\\?\\C:\\BitBucket\\crab6\\product\\installer\\windows\\..\\usage.txt'`

Comment: With respect to interpreting `..`, it's the way to refer to a parent directory. (I might not understand your question.)   Note that `os.path.exists(u'C:\\BitBucket\\crab6\\product\\installer\\windows\\..\\usage.txt')` (without the `\\?\ ` long path syntax) returns `True` as expected.

Comment: In the kernel, ".." components have no special meaning, but most filesystems reserve them as an invalid component name. The only exception I know of is in the target path of a relative symlink; in that one case the system I/O manager parses ".." components like a Unix kernel would because symlinks are supposed to have Unix-like behavior.

Comment: The Windows API usually normalizes file paths as strings before passing them to the native system API. This includes naively resolving ".." components (e.g. "C:\spam\symlink\..\eggs" -> "C:\spam\eggs"). That should make Unix devs recoil in disgust, but it's just the way things work in Windows. Since a "\\?\" verbatim path disables normalization in a create/open context, you'll just have to do it manually, e.g. `os.path.abspath('//?/C:/BitBucket/crab6/product/installer/windows/../usage.txt')` returns `r'\\?\C:\BitBucket\crab6\product\installer\usage.txt'`.

Comment: If the only reason you need a "\\?\" verbatim path is to use a long path, then in Windows 10 with Python 3.6+, you can enable long normalized paths at the system level by setting a DWORD value of 1 named "LongPathsEnabled" in the registry key "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem". It's checked at process startup, so you don't have to reboot the system. Then you won't need the "\\?\" prefix anymore.

Comment: Thank you Eryk Sun, that makes sense.
Regarding LongPathsEnabled, this code has to run on arbitrary Windows machines (including old versions like Windows 7) that are out of my control.